# How to crop an image in Cocos2d

Tags: android, cocos2d-android

I am new to this Cocos2d. i am developing a Tetris type of game. I want to crop an image into small blocks. All i know about this thing is that in iPhone a method called CGImageCreateWithImageInRect is used. Is there any method of this kind is available in android cocos2d or not?

Comment: Why? You can just simply draw a section of a texture if you initialize a sprite with the texture and the rect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created bitmap of that image then crop that bitmap using these code.

```
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.xyz);

resizedbitmap1=Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0,0,yourwidth, yourheight);
```

then converted this bitmap to sprite and this way i solved my issue.